# Leer fichero con vectores dentro de tuplas

Tags: c++, archivo, dev-c++, tuplas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un fichero con el codigo del municipio los partidos que han votado la gente de ese municipio y sus votos. Si no todos los municipios tienen el mismo numero de partidos, como puedo leerlos?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Llevo esto hecho. Me lo copila pero no me funciona, donde esta el error?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas van con el código, los datos de prueba y cualquier error, **siempre como texto** para poder replicar tu problema. Los otros usuarios no compilan con los ojos :P
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Pregunta duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538049/leer-fichero-con-vectores-dentro-de-tuplas